# How to Unmarshal <CarrierIdentifier domain="SCAC">FDE</CarrierIdentifier> this type of XML get value of Domain

Tags: groovy, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am new to XML unmarshaling need help and guidance how I can unmarshal below XML by using JAXB and groovy. I need to create classes but I am not sure how can read the values of AKJ Books in this part of xml:lang field.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
<cXML payloadID="20190205180826780.ShipNotice@Ariba.AKJBooks.com" xml:lang="en-US" timestamp="2019-02-05T18:08:25-05:00">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001332601</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001160200</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001332601</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>XXXXXX</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>AKJBooks Ariba Interface</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request deploymentMode="production">
    <ShipNoticeRequest>
      <ShipNoticeHeader shipmentID="A1464251-426A-4825-80F5-1C85FB530904" noticeDate="2019-02-05T18:06:22-05:00" shipmentDate="2019-02-04T00:00:00-05:00" deliveryDate="2019-02-11T00:00:00-05:00">
        <Contact role="shipFrom">
          <Name xml:lang="en-US">AKJ Books</Name>
          <PostalAddress>
            <Street>4702 Benson Avenue</Street>
            <City>Halethorpe</City>
            <State>MD</State>
            <PostalCode>21227</PostalCode>
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">USA</Country>
          </PostalAddress>
          <Phone>
            <TelephoneNumber>
              <CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
              <AreaOrCityCode>410</AreaOrCityCode>
              <Number>2421602</Number>
            </TelephoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>
        <Comments xml:lang="en-US" />
      </ShipNoticeHeader>
      <ShipControl>
        <CarrierIdentifier domain="SCAC">FDE</CarrierIdentifier>
        <CarrierIdentifier domain="companyName">Federal Express</CarrierIdentifier>
        <ShipmentIdentifier>476352763792</ShipmentIdentifier>
      </ShipControl>
      <ShipNoticePortion>
        <OrderReference orderID="J024157938793101">
          <DocumentReference payloadID="1548443458012.1408509556.OrderRequest@DonorsChoose.org" />
        </OrderReference>
        <ShipNoticeItem quantity="6" lineNumber="1">
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
        </ShipNoticeItem>
        <ShipNoticeItem quantity="6" lineNumber="2">
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
      </ShipNoticePortion>
    </ShipNoticeRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

Comment: Your question is very scant on detail and code, and to help you, please first help us by improving your question. Tell the details, show the pertinent code, preferably a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, and most important, write your question with your audience in mind -- think "what will they need to know to fully understand my problem and code and be able to help me"

Comment: Your title refers to the `CarrierIdentifier` node, but the question body refers to the value of the `ShipNoticeHeader.Contact` -- please update the title or question body to align. You also mention you think you need to create classes, but it's not clear what you mean. Please edit your question as it's not clear whether there's 1, 2, or 3 different queries in it.

Answer (score 0):

First, your XML is invalid. It's missing a closing `</ShipNoticeItem>` towards the end. Once you fix that, though:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def xml = '''<cXML payloadID="20190205180826780.ShipNotice@Ariba.AKJBooks.com" xml:lang="en-US" timestamp="2019-02-05T18:08:25-05:00">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001332601</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001160200</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="NetworkId">
        <Identity>AN01001332601</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>XXXXXX</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>AKJBooks Ariba Interface</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request deploymentMode="production">
    <ShipNoticeRequest>
      <ShipNoticeHeader shipmentID="A1464251-426A-4825-80F5-1C85FB530904" noticeDate="2019-02-05T18:06:22-05:00" shipmentDate="2019-02-04T00:00:00-05:00" deliveryDate="2019-02-11T00:00:00-05:00">
        <Contact role="shipFrom">
          <Name xml:lang="en-US">AKJ Books</Name>
          <PostalAddress>
            <Street>4702 Benson Avenue</Street>
            <City>Halethorpe</City>
            <State>MD</State>
            <PostalCode>21227</PostalCode>
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">USA</Country>
          </PostalAddress>
          <Phone>
            <TelephoneNumber>
              <CountryCode isoCountryCode="US">1</CountryCode>
              <AreaOrCityCode>410</AreaOrCityCode>
              <Number>2421602</Number>
            </TelephoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>
        <Comments xml:lang="en-US" />
      </ShipNoticeHeader>
      <ShipControl>
        <CarrierIdentifier domain="SCAC">FDE</CarrierIdentifier>
        <CarrierIdentifier domain="companyName">Federal Express</CarrierIdentifier>
        <ShipmentIdentifier>476352763792</ShipmentIdentifier>
      </ShipControl>
      <ShipNoticePortion>
        <OrderReference orderID="J024157938793101">
          <DocumentReference payloadID="1548443458012.1408509556.OrderRequest@DonorsChoose.org" />
        </OrderReference>
        <ShipNoticeItem quantity="6" lineNumber="1">
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
        </ShipNoticeItem>
        <ShipNoticeItem quantity="6" lineNumber="2">
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
        </ShipNoticeItem>  
      </ShipNoticePortion>
    </ShipNoticeRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
'''

def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText xml

println parsed.Request.ShipNoticeRequest.ShipNoticeHeader.Contact.Name.text()
```

`==> AKJ Books`

You use the XmlSlurper to parse the xml, and then just walk down the tree to the node you want.